# Speaker (Realtek(R) Audio) not working. Audio services are not responding

Tags: windows-10, audio, troubleshooting, speakers, hp-envy

I haven't heard a sound on my laptop in a week (**HP Envy 13**-**6 months old**). On headphones the sound works perfectly, but when I take off the headphones the whole laptop goes silent. I tried several solutions found on the internet: updating the sound driver, disabling / activating the driver, uninstalling / installing the driver, restarting audio services, using HP Support Assistant, updating Windows, resetting the PC, but also using Windows troubleshooter. I mean, everything I found on the internet. After running the Windows troubleshooter, it says "**Audio services are not responding**" "**Unresolved**". I have no idea what the problem might be. I hope you can help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
-First of all, make sure you have all your drivers updated.
Then go to Audio Settings from the notification icon (on system tray), uncheck all audio enhancements and effects and restart your computer. If it's not fixed, the next step is to go to Device Manager -> Sound, video and game controllers and delete the driver (and restart).

Solution 2:
-Hit "Windows key + R" and type "services.msc". Once services are open, find Windows Audio and Windows Audio Endpoint Builder, right click on each of them -> Properties and change them to automatic, then restart those two services. And restart your computer.

Solution 3:
-If none of this work try opening cmd as admin and type this:
net localgroup Administrators /add networkservice

If the command completed successfully, paste the next command:
net localgroup Administrators /add localservice
(and then restart).

Solution 4:
-Open the Run dialog box (Windows key + R).
Type regedit into the textbox.
Click on the OK button to open Registry Editor.
Expand HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SYSTEM -> CurrentControlSet -> Services -> AudioEndPointBuilder one by one.
Select Parameters.
Find "ServiceDll" from the right and check the information under Data column.
If the value data is not %SystemRoot%\System32\AudioEndPointBuilder.dll., double click on "ServiceDll" and change it.
Close Registry and restart.

Finally, the last option is to open cmd as admin and type those commands one by one:
"sfc /scannow"
and then
"DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth"

-If nothing works, then you have a choice of fresh installation of Windows. If that doesn't work too, it may be an overall speaker's problem and not the drivers...But I think you'll be fine.

Let me know what happened!